# Response.Redirect that does POST instead of GET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am looking for a method that will forward my form post. I have an outside source posting me SAML, I need them to POST to my defualt page to create a cookie before I can redirect them to the page they can operate on. The issue I am having is when I redirect them to the page they can work on the form variables (post data) is lost. I can see in fiddler I am receiving their SAML in the WebForms, but when I response.redirect to the next page, the form data is gone. I understand this is because response.redirect does a get, I was wondering if someone knew of another method, or solution to this problem. Thanks in advance.

Client Posts Saml To My default page -> my default page redirects to a shopping page (because the shopping page creates a non-user cookie) -> the shopping page then redirects to a results page (the results are based off of what is in the saml). Short: I need to preserve the initial SAML posted to me across multiple pages so I can process it on my results page. I would like to continually post it to each intermediate page.

Comment: have you tried Server.Transfer?

Comment: Yeah I tried and looked into server.trasfer it was giving me a 500 error. Is my best bet going to be diving into why I am getting that error, or is there another way?

Comment: @AnthonyDahlberg, you were probably getting the `500` error because you weren't transferring the `Form` data during the transfer.

Comment: I'm not clear on the sequence of events here. Can you edit your question to include a point by point sequence of events that you wish to create.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud can you please explain how to transfer the form data during the transfer?

Comment: And I am getting the 500 error with server.transfer because I am doing 2 transfers, and the first intermediate transfer that creates the cookie is not running the code because server.transfer does not wait. So then when it tries to do the second transfer, it hits a page that requires cookie info for access and breaks.

Comment: Looks like for the initial transfer Server.TransferRequest worked. Server.Transfer worked fine  once my cookie was established. Reasoning: http://forums.iis.net/t/1146511.aspx. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

Write a POST form to the page, fill in the data, and also write some JS code that triggers a submit. For example ADFS does this with SAML tokens.